# What is the mean of the coupled of heat operator coupled with Ricci flow

Tags: partial-differential-equations, ricci-flow

I have some problem when I read  [Entropy and heat kernel bounds on a Ricci flow background](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.07093.pdf).

In the page 6 (I don't know why I can't upload picture), I don't know what is the mean of the coupled of heat operator coupled with Ricci flow. The heat operator is
$$
\square = \partial_t -\Delta_{g_t}
$$

Does it only means that the $g_t$ of $\Delta_{g_t}$ satisfy Ricci flow ?

Comment: It means that the Laplacian is defined with respect to the geometry induced by $g_t$.

Comment: @Tobsn  Thank you.